# Is it safe to remove linux-image with autoremove command?

Tags: apt, package-management, linux-headers

I ran `sudo apt-get autoremove` and this list of packages came up:

```
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  fonts-horai-umefont fonts-wqy-microhei gnome-exe-thumbnailer icoutils
  libasn1-8-heimdal:i386 libcapi20-3 libcapi20-3:i386 libexif12:i386
  libgd3:i386 libgif4 libgif4:i386 libglu1-mesa:i386 libgphoto2-6:i386
  libgphoto2-port10:i386 libgssapi3-heimdal:i386
  libgstreamer-plugins-base0.10-0:i386 libgstreamer0.10-0:i386
  libhcrypto4-heimdal:i386 libheimbase1-heimdal:i386 libheimntlm0-heimdal:i386
  libhx509-5-heimdal:i386 libieee1284-3:i386 libkrb5-26-heimdal:i386
  liblcms2-2:i386 libldap-2.4-2:i386 libltdl7:i386 libmpg123-0:i386 libodbc1
  libopenal1:i386 libosmesa6 libosmesa6:i386 libp11-kit-gnome-keyring:i386
  libroken18-heimdal:i386 libsane:i386 libsasl2-2:i386 libsasl2-modules:i386
  libsasl2-modules-db:i386 libusb-1.0-0:i386 libv4l-0:i386 libv4lconvert0:i386
  libvpx1:i386 libwind0-heimdal:i386 libxcomposite1:i386 libxcursor1:i386
  libxinerama1:i386 libxpm4:i386 libxrandr2:i386 linux-headers-3.13.0-32
  linux-headers-3.13.0-32-generic linux-image-3.13.0-32-generic
  linux-image-extra-3.13.0-32-generic linux-image-generic odbcinst
  odbcinst1debian2 p11-kit-modules:i386 p7zip ttf-wqy-microhei unixodbc
  wine-gecko2.21 wine-gecko2.21:i386 wine-mono0.0.8 winetricks
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 62 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
After this operation, 488 MB disk space will be freed.
```

Most of these looked quite important, especially the Linux images and such. I'm hesitant to remove them, so if anyone could provide some insight that would be great!

Comment: You ran it after doing what?

Comment: @xangua I had done an upgrade and dist-upgrade.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Normally, yes. As long as you have the `linux-image-generic` package installed autoremoving `linux-image-*-generic` packages is safe. This is done to prevent that your `/boot` directory and your GRUB boot menu don't get cluttered of unused kernel images. If you are not sure check that the package removed isn't the same version as your current kernel, which can be verified with `uname -r` and that `linux-image-generic` is manually installed:

```
sudo apt-get install linux-image-generic
```